# Linkedin integration error in signed apk

Tags: android, google-play, linkedin-api, android-keystore, android-app-signing

In my app i have integrated Linkedin successfully. It was working fine in development mode. But the Linkedin shows error on signed apk

> "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST","errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid, unknown, malformed"

I have enrolled both the Package Name & Package Hash in the linkedin development site. I have tried adding and removing the development hash from the linkedin site. It works fine. But on adding hash from keystore is not working for me.

[image]
Can anyone help me? Another problem is I have entered this app in Google playstore with Google Play App Signing. This will double the problem as google will remove the keystore integrated by me? Then how can i integrate the Linkedin? But currently even the apk signed by the keystore from me is not working. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you accidentally (or intentionally) have enabled Google Play Signing Process(Signing V2). If so - then in order to make LinkedIn(or any other hash-configured API) work  - you need to go to Google Play -> Release management -> App Signing. If you have values there - then you indeed have the Signing Process enabled and your APK gets re-signed after upload to Google Play (that's why your key hash doesn't work in LinkedIn). Please take App Signing Certificate SHA-1 value then convert it to Base64 (there are converters online) and then put it into LinkedIn configuration. Hope this helps